# How to attach multiple running processes in gdb?

Tags: c, unix, gdb

How to attach multiple running processes in gdb ?
attached a process to gdb, gdb fails to attach second process.

Comment: here is a good explanation of how to do it: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_25.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add another inferior.

Here is sample gdb session:

```
ks@ks-comp:~$ sleep 1d &
[1] 2917
ks@ks-comp:~$ 
ks@ks-comp:~$ sleep 2d &
[2] 2919
ks@ks-comp:~$ 
ks@ks-comp:~$ gdb -q
(gdb) attach 2919
Attaching to process 2919
Reading symbols from /bin/sleep...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007f81492999a0 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) add-inferior 
Added inferior 2
(gdb) inferior 2
[Switching to inferior 2 [<null>] (<noexec>)]
(gdb) attach 2917
Attaching to process 2917
Reading symbols from /bin/sleep...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007f159f0d29a0 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) i inferiors 
  Num  Description       Executable        
* 2    process 2917      /bin/sleep        
  1    process 2919      /bin/sleep        
(gdb)
```

See [Debugging Multiple Inferiors and Programs](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-Connections-and-Programs.html#Inferiors-Connections-and-Programs)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How can I issue the same debug commands to both process?

Comment: How to add the pid of another process, which has a pid that is not pid2 = pid1 - 2,